# Printing JPEG2000 with PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox, jpeg2000

I'm testing the viability of [`jai-imageio-core`](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/releases/download/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar) and [`jai-imageio-jpeg2000`](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000/releases/download/jai-imageio-jpeg2000-1.4.0/jai-imageio-jpeg2000-1.4.0.jar) for a project that prints [a PDF containing a JPEG2000 encoded image(s)](https://github.com/qzind/tray/files/12421913/jpeg2000.pdf) using [`pdfbox-app`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.29/pdfbox-app-2.0.29.jar).

The [docs for PDFBOX](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#optional-components) state the following:

> These [JPEG2000] libraries are optional and will be loaded if present on the classpath [...].

As a base-line, I'm trying the following:

```bash
 java -cp "./jai-*.jar" -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.29.jar PrintPDF jpeg2000.pdf
```

However, PDFBOX says:

```
Aug 23, 2023 1:38:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine operatorException
SEVERE: Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed
```

... which is the same it says when the JPEG2000 libraries are NOT on the classpath.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK -cp and -jar can't be mixed. Here's what I just tried and it worked:

```
java -cp "pdfbox-app-2.0.29.jar;lib/*" org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PrintPDF -printerName "Microsoft Print to PDF" XXXX\jpeg2000.pdf
```

(On linux the ";" in the classpath needs to be replaced with ":")